# Adding all files using SVN command line

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I tried the below commands to add all files:

```
svn --force add path/to/dir
svn --parents --force add path/to/dir
svn --depth infinity add path/to/dir
```

with all the above possibilities, I am not able to add all the files, only the top folder is getting added other than its files.

Please let me know how to add all the files present in some directory using svn commands.

Comment: What version of svn do you have? The docs say that this should work by default with no extra arguments, and using `--force` should make it work even if some of the intermediate directories are already versioned: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html

Comment: Also, you tagged this with TortoiseSVN. Is there some reason you need to use the command-line as per your title?

Answer (score 0):

Try `svn import`, it is a longer command than `svn add` but it will do the work, if you don't want to add folder by folder with `svn add`.

Comment: Can you explain why an import would be required instead of add? Add is supposed to work recursively. Import is normally not used inside a working copy, but to initialize a new project from an unversioned directory tree.